# Allow java generic types to accept list of T as well as T

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface which performs read and write to a filesystem. Now the question is how i make this interface catering to both List as well as T.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public interface Operations<T> {

    void save(T serializableObject) throws IOException;
    List<T> get() throws IOException;

}
```

The above code should work for both `Operations<List<User>>` as well as `Operations<User>`.

If i have overloaded methods i am going to have a duplicated code

```
@Override
    public void saveCollection(List<T> serializableObjects) throws IOException {
        String jsonData = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(serializableObjects);
        BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        br.write(jsonData);
        br.close();     
    }

    @Override
    public void save(T serializableObject) throws IOException {
        String jsonData = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(serializableObject);
        BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        br.write(jsonData);
        br.close();
    }
```

Comment: No. Types can not be "a or b". If you think about it, you'll realize why: You can't know which type you have. You could try `List<T>` and require callers to make a list of size 1 for single items.

Comment: question unclear.  You have one method that caters for a List<T> and one method that caters for a T.  What more do want, exactly ?  (You can add a third method void save(List<T> ...) to have save cater with lists.  You can add a default implementation that processes all T in the list and calls the save(T ...) method for each.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add method that will accept collection of `T`

```
 void save(T serializableObject) throws IOException;
 void save(Collection<T> listOfTs);
```

Comment: And add a `default` implementation for the `Collection` method if you're using Java 8.

Comment: I already had this idea in my mind. But this creates code duplication.Please check the question with added implementation details.

Comment: @dataEnthusiast why? I would assume that I can always write collection and writing single element is a special case of collection of 1 element. Code kept DRY here without problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about code duplication, why not simply put the common implementation into a separate private method and use your existing overloads to forward their arguments to it?

```
private void saveImpl(Object serializableObject) throws IOException {
    String jsonData = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(serializableObject);
    BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    br.write(jsonData);
    br.close();
}

@Override
public void save(List<T> serializableObjects) throws IOException {
    saveImpl(serializableObjects);
}

@Override
public void save(T serializableObject) throws IOException {
    saveImpl(serializableObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html). The method could look like this:

```
void save(T... objects) throws IOException;
```

which then can be called with

- one argument: `obj.save(myArgument)`
- multiple comma separated arguments: `obj.save(myFirstArgument, mySecondArgument)`
- an array: `obj.save(new MyArgumentType[]{myFirstArgument, mySecondArgument})`